# Dynamically change Vertex Color in Three.js

Tags: three.js

I am using Three.js 57 version.  Now I am working in animation using JSONLoader. I got the animation successfully. But I want to update **full vertex color of mesh for each frame in animation**. Is this possibe in three.js

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Vertex colors are currently not supported in `CanvasRenderer`.

Here is the pattern you need to follow for `WebGLRenderer`:

Set `THREE.VertexColors` when you create the material for the mesh;

```
material.vertexColors = THREE.VertexColors;
```

Also make sure that `vertexColors` are defined for each face of your geometry.

```
geometry.faces[ faceIndex ].vertexColors[ vertexIndex ] = new THREE.Color( 0xff0000 );
```

Then in your render loop, to change a vertex color, do this:

```
geometry.faces[ faceIndex ].vertexColors[ vertexIndex ].setHSL( Math.random(), 0.5, 0.5 );
mesh.geometry.colorsNeedUpdate = true;
```

three.js r.59

Comment: Is faceIndex and vertexIndex automatically defined?

Comment: @schlenger no, you have to do this by yourself. Just added this for completion.

Comment: Interestingly enough to update the color it is necessary to use the .setHSL() function, simply assigning a new THREE.Color() does not update the graph for me.

Comment: @Paul See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37358419/how-to-update-colors-after-vertex-colors-are-changed/37368746#37368746

Comment: It's not necessary to use .setHSL to change the color attribute of a mesh, at least in recent THREE versions